# c++ count whitespaces between numbers (not strings)

Tags: c++, vector

So I have a program that takes in integers from user and puts them in a vector and displays them. however, I want to be able to show the total number of whitespaces between the numbers I put while inputting the numbers also.. I had a look online but couldn't find anything that would work for ints or chars.. I cant use strings or getline right now so idk what to do..
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,count;
    vector<int> numbers;
    while(cin>>a)
    {
       numbers.push_back(a); 
       // count whitespaces??
    }
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<numbers[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so if the input is 1(space)2(space)(space)3(space)
i want to be able to calculate the total spaces in between so in this case count would be 4

Answer (score 0):

Try `getline()`:

```
string str;
getline(cin,str);
```

and then count whitespace in `str`:

```
int wc = 0;
for (auto c: str) wc += (c == ' ');
cout << wc << endl;
```